# Reading the XML file using DOM parser and storing the output into MySQL

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class XMLParser {

    public void getAllUserNames(String fileName) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            File file = new File(fileName);
            if (file.exists()) {
                Document doc = db.parse(file);
                Element docEle = doc.getDocumentElement();

                // Print root element of the document
                System.out.println("Root element of the document: "
                        + docEle.getNodeName());

                NodeList studentList = docEle.getElementsByTagName("student");

                // Print total student elements in document
                System.out
                        .println("Total students: " + studentList.getLength());

                if (studentList != null && studentList.getLength() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < studentList.getLength(); i++) {

                        Node node = studentList.item(i);

                        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                            System.out
                                    .println("=====================");

                            Element e = (Element) node;
                            NodeList nodeList = e.getElementsByTagName("name");
                            System.out.println("Name: "
                                    + nodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0)
                                            .getNodeValue());

                            nodeList = e.getElementsByTagName("grade");
                            System.out.println("Grade: "
                                    + nodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0)
                                            .getNodeValue());

                            nodeList = e.getElementsByTagName("age");
                            System.out.println("Age: "
                                    + nodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0)
                                            .getNodeValue());
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        parser.getAllUserNames("C:/Users/rasika_patil01/Desktop/205_008_JAXBTesterOld/Student.xml");
    }
}
```

Using this code I get an output as :

Output :
Root element of the document: students

## Total students: 4

Name: John
Grade: B

## Age: 12

Name: Mary
Grade: A

## Age: 11

Name: Simon
Grade: A

## Age: 18

Name: Rasika
Grade: A+
Age: 23

I want to store the above output into MySQL. Could anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have the JDBC driver jar for MySQL, either from [Mysql site](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/), or using your dependency manager.
2. To connect from java

   ```
   MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
   dataSource.setUser(user);
   dataSource.setPassword(password);
   dataSource.setServerName(server);
   dataSource.setDatabaseName(database);
   Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();

   PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table (name, grade, age) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

   ...then while going throug the XML:

   stmt.setString(1, name);
   stmt.setString(2, grade);
   stmt.setString(3, age);
   stmt.execute();

   ...at the end:
   stmt.close();
   conn.commit();
   conn.close()
   ```

Use the actual database connection parameters, and database table names, column names, column types.